# UV unwrapping not working, point appearing at the bottom left of the image

Tags: uv

everything is in title and picture, I just don't understand. Can you help me?
[image: Edit mode and uv editor]

Comment: check that you have applied scale to your model.

Comment: You have to mark seams or use the smart uv project function. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/uv_image/uv/editing/unwrapping/seams.html

Comment: It worked ! Thank you !